# Venobox displays images partly, on the bottom of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm using venobox to display pictures on my website, or at least I'm trying. But when I click on the thumbnail it displays part of the image on the bottom of the screen. So I can only see the top part of the image.

This part is from the header of the html file

```
<!-- Add venobox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="venobox/venobox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="venobox/venobox.js"></script>
```

This part is in the div where the image thumbnails are displayed

```
<div>
    <h5>De springplank 2011</h5>
    <a class="venobox" data-gall="gallery1" href="images/1.jpg"><img src="images/thumb-1.jpg"/></a>
    <a class="venobox" data-gall="gallery1" href="images/2.jpg"><img src="images/thumb-2.jpg"/></a>
    <a class="venobox" data-gall="gallery1" href="images/3.jpg"><img src="images/thumb-3.jpg"/></a>
    <a class="venobox" data-gall="gallery1" href="images/4.jpg"><img      src="images/thumb-4.jpg"/></a>
    </div>
```

And this part is just before the end of the body, as described in the instruction.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

/* default settings */
$('.venobox').venobox(); 


/* custom settings */
$('.venobox_custom').venobox({
    framewidth: '400px',        // default: ''
    frameheight: '300px',       // default: ''
    border: '10px',             // default: '0'
    bgcolor: '#5dff5e',         // default: '#fff'
    titleattr: 'data-title',    // default: 'title'
    numeratio: true,            // default: false
    infinigall: true            // default: false
});

/* auto-open #firstlink on page load */
$("#firstlink").venobox().trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

And this is the instruction I followed: http://lab.veno.it/venobox/

So if any of you could help me that'd be awesome!

Sorry for not showing a picture, apparently one has to have a reputation of at least 10.

Comment: you can allways upload it somewhere and share a link... I think

Comment: Try css around with the ```vbox-content``` Class. For more a more detailed approach a screenshot and some css code would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it by adding this to my css file:

> .vbox-content{
>      margin-top: 9px !important;
>   }

The plugin dynamically generates its own high top margin value for vbox-content class, so you have to include the !important to enforce your own.

Good luck.